How can one tell if an egg is a regular cooked egg or an egg balut?
I can tell whether a egg is cooked by observing its spinning pattern. But how can one tell if an egg is a regular cooked egg or an egg balut (without opening or damaging the egg)?

You might be able to with candling, but I think would only work with early balut

@Sneftel thanks, good point, I have just accepted answers for all my questions. I cannot upvote though because I had already upvoted all answers, except one that I had forgotten).

What's an "egg balut"?

@PeteBecker https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balut_(food)

If I had to differentiate between both of them, I'd probably be looking at what I'm buying and just keeping them strictly separated afterwards, so as not to accidentally eat/open the balut ones :-P I'm curious, what prompted this question, how did you get the two mixed up?

@Tinkeringbell Thanks, 2 use cases: language barrier with street sellers (my attempt at mimicking a small chicken to try to ask if the egg was balut went poorly) and my short-term memory about item placement in the fridge.

I suspect that there's absolutely nothing practical you can do at that point. While raw, you could candle the egg to look for the embryo; but a candled boiled egg will just be opaque. If the egg had been boiled/steamed in an upright position then a balut egg would tend to roll to the same position on the side while an unfertilized egg would not significantly favor one side, but balut eggs wouldn't normally be cooked like that. I think you'd have to use an X-ray to see the differences.
